# How to convert a PHP regular expression to jQuery?

Tags: jquery, regex

I found many threads on Stack Overflow but most of them are providing regex expressions in PHP. Also, those are in jQuery are not the exact one that what I need for.

Following regex expression is working perfectly fine in PHP but not working in jQuery. Also, this one is more precise rather than manually excluding special characters and adding ranges of Unicode characters.

```
[^\p{L}\p{Z}\p{N}\p{M}]
```

You can also test it on [regex](https://regex101.com/r/qH1uG3/11).

How can I convert this syntax to JavaScript?

Comment: So, with this regex, you plan to match punctuation and symbols only? Shouldn't you actually be looking for an equivalent of `[\p{P}\p{S}]`? I think this one will turn out shorter since you will still have to use Unicode ranges. It is advised to use XRegExp that supports Unicode category classes if you need that precision.

Comment: Actually, I want to exclude all special characters. I'm dynamically creating the form fields with user provided input that should work for all languages. If someone adds special character then it disturbs "class", "id" attributes of input and breaks all the code.

Comment: So, an XRegExp seems a solution for you.

Comment: Could you please share exact syntax for this? You can also test it to https://regex101.com/ and share with me a resulted output.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, Thanks for your solution. I have tested it on but it's not excluding the special characters. https://regex101.com/r/hGxwFM/3/

Comment: That is because you did not use `XRegExp`. It is a common error to test something that is not supported in the target environment at regex testing sites.

Comment: OOPs. Sorry, that is my mistake. Will let you know in a while after testing.

Comment: Without an attempt at writing the code in the correct language, this question is a request for free work, and can be closed as "too broad". Questions that contain "please help me do X" are better phrased as "how can I do X", assuming the speaker is keen to try it themselves.

Comment: "Could you please share exact syntax for this and share with me" is **explicitly a request for free work**. Please do be willing to try - we get this with regexs a lot on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I agreed with your second comment. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to match all punctuation (`\p{P}`) and all symbols (`\p{S}`). You may use [XRegExp library](http://xregexp.com/syntax/) for this as it supports all the Unicode category classes in regex:

```js
var s ="@#$#$sadsadà¤¸à¥à¤Ÿà¥ˆà¤• à¤“à¤µà¤°à¤«à¥à¤²à¥‹ 123213|'\"+";
var rx = new XRegExp("[\\pP\\pS]+", "g");
console.log(XRegExp.replace(s, rx, ""));
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/3.2.0/xregexp-all.min.js"></script>
```

Note that `XRegExp("[\\pP\\pS]+", "g")` defines a regex that matches one or more (`+`) characters that are either punctuation (`\pP`) or symbols (`\pS`) and replaces them with an empty string globally.

Actually, you may use your regex with `XRegExp`, too.

Currently, `\p{P}` (punctuation) can be represented with

```
var rx_pP = "[\\x21-\\x23\\x25-\\x2A\\x2C-\\x2F\\x3A\\x3B\\x3F\\x40\\x5B-\\x5D\\x5F\\x7B\\x7D\\xA1\\xA7\\xAB\\xB6\\xB7\\xBB\\xBF\\u037E\\u0387\\u055A-\\u055F\\u0589\\u058A\\u05BE\\u05C0\\u05C3\\u05C6\\u05F3\\u05F4\\u0609\\u060A\\u060C\\u060D\\u061B\\u061E\\u061F\\u066A-\\u066D\\u06D4\\u0700-\\u070D\\u07F7-\\u07F9\\u0830-\\u083E\\u085E\\u0964\\u0965\\u0970\\u0AF0\\u0DF4\\u0E4F\\u0E5A\\u0E5B\\u0F04-\\u0F12\\u0F14\\u0F3A-\\u0F3D\\u0F85\\u0FD0-\\u0FD4\\u0FD9\\u0FDA\\u104A-\\u104F\\u10FB\\u1360-\\u1368\\u1400\\u166D\\u166E\\u169B\\u169C\\u16EB-\\u16ED\\u1735\\u1736\\u17D4-\\u17D6\\u17D8-\\u17DA\\u1800-\\u180A\\u1944\\u1945\\u1A1E\\u1A1F\\u1AA0-\\u1AA6\\u1AA8-\\u1AAD\\u1B5A-\\u1B60\\u1BFC-\\u1BFF\\u1C3B-\\u1C3F\\u1C7E\\u1C7F\\u1CC0-\\u1CC7\\u1CD3\\u2010-\\u2027\\u2030-\\u2043\\u2045-\\u2051\\u2053-\\u205E\\u207D\\u207E\\u208D\\u208E\\u2308-\\u230B\\u2329\\u232A\\u2768-\\u2775\\u27C5\\u27C6\\u27E6-\\u27EF\\u2983-\\u2998\\u29D8-\\u29DB\\u29FC\\u29FD\\u2CF9-\\u2CFC\\u2CFE\\u2CFF\\u2D70\\u2E00-\\u2E2E\\u2E30-\\u2E44\\u3001-\\u3003\\u3008-\\u3011\\u3014-\\u301F\\u3030\\u303D\\u30A0\\u30FB\\uA4FE\\uA4FF\\uA60D-\\uA60F\\uA673\\uA67E\\uA6F2-\\uA6F7\\uA874-\\uA877\\uA8CE\\uA8CF\\uA8F8-\\uA8FA\\uA8FC\\uA92E\\uA92F\\uA95F\\uA9C1-\\uA9CD\\uA9DE\\uA9DF\\uAA5C-\\uAA5F\\uAADE\\uAADF\\uAAF0\\uAAF1\\uABEB\\uFD3E\\uFD3F\\uFE10-\\uFE19\\uFE30-\\uFE52\\uFE54-\\uFE61\\uFE63\\uFE68\\uFE6A\\uFE6B\\uFF01-\\uFF03\\uFF05-\\uFF0A\\uFF0C-\\uFF0F\\uFF1A\\uFF1B\\uFF1F\\uFF20\\uFF3B-\\uFF3D\\uFF3F\\uFF5B\\uFF5D\\uFF5F-\\uFF65]|\\uD800[\\uDD00-\\uDD02\\uDF9F\\uDFD0]|\\uD801\\uDD6F|\\uD802[\\uDC57\\uDD1F\\uDD3F\\uDE50-\\uDE58\\uDE7F\\uDEF0-\\uDEF6\\uDF39-\\uDF3F\\uDF99-\\uDF9C]|\\uD804[\\uDC47-\\uDC4D\\uDCBB\\uDCBC\\uDCBE-\\uDCC1\\uDD40-\\uDD43\\uDD74\\uDD75\\uDDC5-\\uDDC9\\uDDCD\\uDDDB\\uDDDD-\\uDDDF\\uDE38-\\uDE3D\\uDEA9]|\\uD805[\\uDC4B-\\uDC4F\\uDC5B\\uDC5D\\uDCC6\\uDDC1-\\uDDD7\\uDE41-\\uDE43\\uDE60-\\uDE6C\\uDF3C-\\uDF3E]|\\uD807[\\uDC41-\\uDC45\\uDC70\\uDC71]|\\uD809[\\uDC70-\\uDC74]|\\uD81A[\\uDE6E\\uDE6F\\uDEF5\\uDF37-\\uDF3B\\uDF44]|\\uD82F\\uDC9F|\\uD836[\\uDE87-\\uDE8B]|\\uD83A[\\uDD5E\\uDD5F]";
```

And `\p{S}` can be described as

```
var rx_pS = "[\\x24\\x2B\\x3C-\\x3E\\x5E\\x60\\x7C\\x7E\\xA2-\\xA6\\xA8\\xA9\\xAC\\xAE-\\xB1\\xB4\\xB8\\xD7\\xF7\\u02C2-\\u02C5\\u02D2-\\u02DF\\u02E5-\\u02EB\\u02ED\\u02EF-\\u02FF\\u0375\\u0384\\u0385\\u03F6\\u0482\\u058D-\\u058F\\u0606-\\u0608\\u060B\\u060E\\u060F\\u06DE\\u06E9\\u06FD\\u06FE\\u07F6\\u09F2\\u09F3\\u09FA\\u09FB\\u0AF1\\u0B70\\u0BF3-\\u0BFA\\u0C7F\\u0D4F\\u0D79\\u0E3F\\u0F01-\\u0F03\\u0F13\\u0F15-\\u0F17\\u0F1A-\\u0F1F\\u0F34\\u0F36\\u0F38\\u0FBE-\\u0FC5\\u0FC7-\\u0FCC\\u0FCE\\u0FCF\\u0FD5-\\u0FD8\\u109E\\u109F\\u1390-\\u1399\\u17DB\\u1940\\u19DE-\\u19FF\\u1B61-\\u1B6A\\u1B74-\\u1B7C\\u1FBD\\u1FBF-\\u1FC1\\u1FCD-\\u1FCF\\u1FDD-\\u1FDF\\u1FED-\\u1FEF\\u1FFD\\u1FFE\\u2044\\u2052\\u207A-\\u207C\\u208A-\\u208C\\u20A0-\\u20BE\\u2100\\u2101\\u2103-\\u2106\\u2108\\u2109\\u2114\\u2116-\\u2118\\u211E-\\u2123\\u2125\\u2127\\u2129\\u212E\\u213A\\u213B\\u2140-\\u2144\\u214A-\\u214D\\u214F\\u218A\\u218B\\u2190-\\u2307\\u230C-\\u2328\\u232B-\\u23FE\\u2400-\\u2426\\u2440-\\u244A\\u249C-\\u24E9\\u2500-\\u2767\\u2794-\\u27C4\\u27C7-\\u27E5\\u27F0-\\u2982\\u2999-\\u29D7\\u29DC-\\u29FB\\u29FE-\\u2B73\\u2B76-\\u2B95\\u2B98-\\u2BB9\\u2BBD-\\u2BC8\\u2BCA-\\u2BD1\\u2BEC-\\u2BEF\\u2CE5-\\u2CEA\\u2E80-\\u2E99\\u2E9B-\\u2EF3\\u2F00-\\u2FD5\\u2FF0-\\u2FFB\\u3004\\u3012\\u3013\\u3020\\u3036\\u3037\\u303E\\u303F\\u309B\\u309C\\u3190\\u3191\\u3196-\\u319F\\u31C0-\\u31E3\\u3200-\\u321E\\u322A-\\u3247\\u3250\\u3260-\\u327F\\u328A-\\u32B0\\u32C0-\\u32FE\\u3300-\\u33FF\\u4DC0-\\u4DFF\\uA490-\\uA4C6\\uA700-\\uA716\\uA720\\uA721\\uA789\\uA78A\\uA828-\\uA82B\\uA836-\\uA839\\uAA77-\\uAA79\\uAB5B\\uFB29\\uFBB2-\\uFBC1\\uFDFC\\uFDFD\\uFE62\\uFE64-\\uFE66\\uFE69\\uFF04\\uFF0B\\uFF1C-\\uFF1E\\uFF3E\\uFF40\\uFF5C\\uFF5E\\uFFE0-\\uFFE6\\uFFE8-\\uFFEE\\uFFFC\\uFFFD]|\\uD800[\\uDD37-\\uDD3F\\uDD79-\\uDD89\\uDD8C-\\uDD8E\\uDD90-\\uDD9B\\uDDA0\\uDDD0-\\uDDFC]|\\uD802[\\uDC77\\uDC78\\uDEC8]|\\uD805\\uDF3F|\\uD81A[\\uDF3C-\\uDF3F\\uDF45]|\\uD82F\\uDC9C|\\uD834[\\uDC00-\\uDCF5\\uDD00-\\uDD26\\uDD29-\\uDD64\\uDD6A-\\uDD6C\\uDD83\\uDD84\\uDD8C-\\uDDA9\\uDDAE-\\uDDE8\\uDE00-\\uDE41\\uDE45\\uDF00-\\uDF56]|\\uD835[\\uDEC1\\uDEDB\\uDEFB\\uDF15\\uDF35\\uDF4F\\uDF6F\\uDF89\\uDFA9\\uDFC3]|\\uD836[\\uDC00-\\uDDFF\\uDE37-\\uDE3A\\uDE6D-\\uDE74\\uDE76-\\uDE83\\uDE85\\uDE86]|\\uD83B[\\uDEF0\\uDEF1]|\\uD83C[\\uDC00-\\uDC2B\\uDC30-\\uDC93\\uDCA0-\\uDCAE\\uDCB1-\\uDCBF\\uDCC1-\\uDCCF\\uDCD1-\\uDCF5\\uDD10-\\uDD2E\\uDD30-\\uDD6B\\uDD70-\\uDDAC\\uDDE6-\\uDE02\\uDE10-\\uDE3B\\uDE40-\\uDE48\\uDE50\\uDE51\\uDF00-\\uDFFF]|\\uD83D[\\uDC00-\\uDED2\\uDEE0-\\uDEEC\\uDEF0-\\uDEF6\\uDF00-\\uDF73\\uDF80-\\uDFD4]|\\uD83E[\\uDC00-\\uDC0B\\uDC10-\\uDC47\\uDC50-\\uDC59\\uDC60-\\uDC87\\uDC90-\\uDCAD\\uDD10-\\uDD1E\\uDD20-\\uDD27\\uDD30\\uDD33-\\uDD3E\\uDD40-\\uDD4B\\uDD50-\\uDD5E\\uDD80-\\uDD91\\uDDC0]";
```

And the vanilla JS code you may use will look like

```js
var rx_pP = "[\\x21-\\x23\\x25-\\x2A\\x2C-\\x2F\\x3A\\x3B\\x3F\\x40\\x5B-\\x5D\\x5F\\x7B\\x7D\\xA1\\xA7\\xAB\\xB6\\xB7\\xBB\\xBF\\u037E\\u0387\\u055A-\\u055F\\u0589\\u058A\\u05BE\\u05C0\\u05C3\\u05C6\\u05F3\\u05F4\\u0609\\u060A\\u060C\\u060D\\u061B\\u061E\\u061F\\u066A-\\u066D\\u06D4\\u0700-\\u070D\\u07F7-\\u07F9\\u0830-\\u083E\\u085E\\u0964\\u0965\\u0970\\u0AF0\\u0DF4\\u0E4F\\u0E5A\\u0E5B\\u0F04-\\u0F12\\u0F14\\u0F3A-\\u0F3D\\u0F85\\u0FD0-\\u0FD4\\u0FD9\\u0FDA\\u104A-\\u104F\\u10FB\\u1360-\\u1368\\u1400\\u166D\\u166E\\u169B\\u169C\\u16EB-\\u16ED\\u1735\\u1736\\u17D4-\\u17D6\\u17D8-\\u17DA\\u1800-\\u180A\\u1944\\u1945\\u1A1E\\u1A1F\\u1AA0-\\u1AA6\\u1AA8-\\u1AAD\\u1B5A-\\u1B60\\u1BFC-\\u1BFF\\u1C3B-\\u1C3F\\u1C7E\\u1C7F\\u1CC0-\\u1CC7\\u1CD3\\u2010-\\u2027\\u2030-\\u2043\\u2045-\\u2051\\u2053-\\u205E\\u207D\\u207E\\u208D\\u208E\\u2308-\\u230B\\u2329\\u232A\\u2768-\\u2775\\u27C5\\u27C6\\u27E6-\\u27EF\\u2983-\\u2998\\u29D8-\\u29DB\\u29FC\\u29FD\\u2CF9-\\u2CFC\\u2CFE\\u2CFF\\u2D70\\u2E00-\\u2E2E\\u2E30-\\u2E44\\u3001-\\u3003\\u3008-\\u3011\\u3014-\\u301F\\u3030\\u303D\\u30A0\\u30FB\\uA4FE\\uA4FF\\uA60D-\\uA60F\\uA673\\uA67E\\uA6F2-\\uA6F7\\uA874-\\uA877\\uA8CE\\uA8CF\\uA8F8-\\uA8FA\\uA8FC\\uA92E\\uA92F\\uA95F\\uA9C1-\\uA9CD\\uA9DE\\uA9DF\\uAA5C-\\uAA5F\\uAADE\\uAADF\\uAAF0\\uAAF1\\uABEB\\uFD3E\\uFD3F\\uFE10-\\uFE19\\uFE30-\\uFE52\\uFE54-\\uFE61\\uFE63\\uFE68\\uFE6A\\uFE6B\\uFF01-\\uFF03\\uFF05-\\uFF0A\\uFF0C-\\uFF0F\\uFF1A\\uFF1B\\uFF1F\\uFF20\\uFF3B-\\uFF3D\\uFF3F\\uFF5B\\uFF5D\\uFF5F-\\uFF65]|\\uD800[\\uDD00-\\uDD02\\uDF9F\\uDFD0]|\\uD801\\uDD6F|\\uD802[\\uDC57\\uDD1F\\uDD3F\\uDE50-\\uDE58\\uDE7F\\uDEF0-\\uDEF6\\uDF39-\\uDF3F\\uDF99-\\uDF9C]|\\uD804[\\uDC47-\\uDC4D\\uDCBB\\uDCBC\\uDCBE-\\uDCC1\\uDD40-\\uDD43\\uDD74\\uDD75\\uDDC5-\\uDDC9\\uDDCD\\uDDDB\\uDDDD-\\uDDDF\\uDE38-\\uDE3D\\uDEA9]|\\uD805[\\uDC4B-\\uDC4F\\uDC5B\\uDC5D\\uDCC6\\uDDC1-\\uDDD7\\uDE41-\\uDE43\\uDE60-\\uDE6C\\uDF3C-\\uDF3E]|\\uD807[\\uDC41-\\uDC45\\uDC70\\uDC71]|\\uD809[\\uDC70-\\uDC74]|\\uD81A[\\uDE6E\\uDE6F\\uDEF5\\uDF37-\\uDF3B\\uDF44]|\\uD82F\\uDC9F|\\uD836[\\uDE87-\\uDE8B]|\\uD83A[\\uDD5E\\uDD5F]";

var rx_pS = "[\\x24\\x2B\\x3C-\\x3E\\x5E\\x60\\x7C\\x7E\\xA2-\\xA6\\xA8\\xA9\\xAC\\xAE-\\xB1\\xB4\\xB8\\xD7\\xF7\\u02C2-\\u02C5\\u02D2-\\u02DF\\u02E5-\\u02EB\\u02ED\\u02EF-\\u02FF\\u0375\\u0384\\u0385\\u03F6\\u0482\\u058D-\\u058F\\u0606-\\u0608\\u060B\\u060E\\u060F\\u06DE\\u06E9\\u06FD\\u06FE\\u07F6\\u09F2\\u09F3\\u09FA\\u09FB\\u0AF1\\u0B70\\u0BF3-\\u0BFA\\u0C7F\\u0D4F\\u0D79\\u0E3F\\u0F01-\\u0F03\\u0F13\\u0F15-\\u0F17\\u0F1A-\\u0F1F\\u0F34\\u0F36\\u0F38\\u0FBE-\\u0FC5\\u0FC7-\\u0FCC\\u0FCE\\u0FCF\\u0FD5-\\u0FD8\\u109E\\u109F\\u1390-\\u1399\\u17DB\\u1940\\u19DE-\\u19FF\\u1B61-\\u1B6A\\u1B74-\\u1B7C\\u1FBD\\u1FBF-\\u1FC1\\u1FCD-\\u1FCF\\u1FDD-\\u1FDF\\u1FED-\\u1FEF\\u1FFD\\u1FFE\\u2044\\u2052\\u207A-\\u207C\\u208A-\\u208C\\u20A0-\\u20BE\\u2100\\u2101\\u2103-\\u2106\\u2108\\u2109\\u2114\\u2116-\\u2118\\u211E-\\u2123\\u2125\\u2127\\u2129\\u212E\\u213A\\u213B\\u2140-\\u2144\\u214A-\\u214D\\u214F\\u218A\\u218B\\u2190-\\u2307\\u230C-\\u2328\\u232B-\\u23FE\\u2400-\\u2426\\u2440-\\u244A\\u249C-\\u24E9\\u2500-\\u2767\\u2794-\\u27C4\\u27C7-\\u27E5\\u27F0-\\u2982\\u2999-\\u29D7\\u29DC-\\u29FB\\u29FE-\\u2B73\\u2B76-\\u2B95\\u2B98-\\u2BB9\\u2BBD-\\u2BC8\\u2BCA-\\u2BD1\\u2BEC-\\u2BEF\\u2CE5-\\u2CEA\\u2E80-\\u2E99\\u2E9B-\\u2EF3\\u2F00-\\u2FD5\\u2FF0-\\u2FFB\\u3004\\u3012\\u3013\\u3020\\u3036\\u3037\\u303E\\u303F\\u309B\\u309C\\u3190\\u3191\\u3196-\\u319F\\u31C0-\\u31E3\\u3200-\\u321E\\u322A-\\u3247\\u3250\\u3260-\\u327F\\u328A-\\u32B0\\u32C0-\\u32FE\\u3300-\\u33FF\\u4DC0-\\u4DFF\\uA490-\\uA4C6\\uA700-\\uA716\\uA720\\uA721\\uA789\\uA78A\\uA828-\\uA82B\\uA836-\\uA839\\uAA77-\\uAA79\\uAB5B\\uFB29\\uFBB2-\\uFBC1\\uFDFC\\uFDFD\\uFE62\\uFE64-\\uFE66\\uFE69\\uFF04\\uFF0B\\uFF1C-\\uFF1E\\uFF3E\\uFF40\\uFF5C\\uFF5E\\uFFE0-\\uFFE6\\uFFE8-\\uFFEE\\uFFFC\\uFFFD]|\\uD800[\\uDD37-\\uDD3F\\uDD79-\\uDD89\\uDD8C-\\uDD8E\\uDD90-\\uDD9B\\uDDA0\\uDDD0-\\uDDFC]|\\uD802[\\uDC77\\uDC78\\uDEC8]|\\uD805\\uDF3F|\\uD81A[\\uDF3C-\\uDF3F\\uDF45]|\\uD82F\\uDC9C|\\uD834[\\uDC00-\\uDCF5\\uDD00-\\uDD26\\uDD29-\\uDD64\\uDD6A-\\uDD6C\\uDD83\\uDD84\\uDD8C-\\uDDA9\\uDDAE-\\uDDE8\\uDE00-\\uDE41\\uDE45\\uDF00-\\uDF56]|\\uD835[\\uDEC1\\uDEDB\\uDEFB\\uDF15\\uDF35\\uDF4F\\uDF6F\\uDF89\\uDFA9\\uDFC3]|\\uD836[\\uDC00-\\uDDFF\\uDE37-\\uDE3A\\uDE6D-\\uDE74\\uDE76-\\uDE83\\uDE85\\uDE86]|\\uD83B[\\uDEF0\\uDEF1]|\\uD83C[\\uDC00-\\uDC2B\\uDC30-\\uDC93\\uDCA0-\\uDCAE\\uDCB1-\\uDCBF\\uDCC1-\\uDCCF\\uDCD1-\\uDCF5\\uDD10-\\uDD2E\\uDD30-\\uDD6B\\uDD70-\\uDDAC\\uDDE6-\\uDE02\\uDE10-\\uDE3B\\uDE40-\\uDE48\\uDE50\\uDE51\\uDF00-\\uDFFF]|\\uD83D[\\uDC00-\\uDED2\\uDEE0-\\uDEEC\\uDEF0-\\uDEF6\\uDF00-\\uDF73\\uDF80-\\uDFD4]|\\uD83E[\\uDC00-\\uDC0B\\uDC10-\\uDC47\\uDC50-\\uDC59\\uDC60-\\uDC87\\uDC90-\\uDCAD\\uDD10-\\uDD1E\\uDD20-\\uDD27\\uDD30\\uDD33-\\uDD3E\\uDD40-\\uDD4B\\uDD50-\\uDD5E\\uDD80-\\uDD91\\uDDC0]";

var s ="@#$#$sadsadà¤¸à¥à¤Ÿà¥ˆà¤• à¤“à¤µà¤°à¤«à¥à¤²à¥‹ 123213|'\"+";
var rx = new RegExp(rx_pP + "|" + rx_pS, "g");
console.log(s.replace(rx, ""));
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for your help. I have tested your first provided solution and it worked like a charm.

Comment: It is preferred to use XRegExp, since the library is updated regularly to reflect changes in the Unicode standard.

Comment: I have also one question. If I write this expression in regex but not use the  XRegExp library than what will the syntax for it?

Comment: I provided the equivalent as the second solution. It is based on XRegExp 3.2.0.